# how do I download multiple files using gsutil?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to download multiple files from UGC YouTube dataset. for this I installed Google Cloud SDK and used this command in Google Cloud SDK shell:

```
gsutil -m cp \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-05f8.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-0c4f.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-18f5.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-209f.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-21dd.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-2fbe.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-2fff.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-3d67.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-3dbf.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-3e01.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-4214.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-4be3.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-4ea8.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-5083.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-58d3.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-5dd8.mkv" \
  "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-646f.mkv" \
  .
```

but when I entered the above command in the shell it produced this error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

but when I just try to download one file it works:

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_1080P-05f8.mkv "E:/UGC/Animation/output8mb"
```

what should I do to download multiple files?

Comment: Based on that error message, I think you're using the DoS command shell. You might try installing cygwin and using that shell instead. It's a more featureful and friendly shell, and I just tried the gsutil command you tried above in cygwin, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

`gsutil` command can be used with `glob style pattern` to copy several files :

```bash
gsutil -m cp -r "gs://ugc-dataset/original_videos/Animation/1080P/Animation_*.mkv" \
  .
```

Comment: I just remove the " " and \ and put space instead of them and put the saving directory like this "E:/UGC/Animation/output8mb", it works for me after these changes.

Comment: Yes I ran this command in a zsh on my side, that’s why I have the "" chars